# GlazedLists and JTable with multiple sources

Tags: java, jtable, glazedlists

I have 3 `ArrayList`s and a `JTable`.
I would like to be able to add/edit/remove elements from the *selected* (from one of the 3) `ArrayList` by selecting the elements in the `JTable` and for example clicking on a button.

I have this code for using only one `ArrayList`:

```
/* ... */
EventList<MyClass> eventList = GlazedLists.eventList(myFirstArrayList);
SortedList<MyClass> sortedList = new SortedList<MyClass>(eventList, null);
filterList = new FilterList<MyClass>(sortedList);
EventTableModel<MyClass> listModel = new EventTableModel<MyClass>(filterList,
        myTableFormat);
table.setModel(listModel);
TableComparatorChooser.install(table, sortedList,
        AbstractTableComparatorChooser.MULTIPLE_COLUMN_MOUSE);
selectionModel = new EventSelectionModel<MyClass>(filterList);
table.setSelectionModel(selectionModel);
/* ... */
```

How could I change the *source* of the `EventList` or the `FilterList` to the 2. or the 3. `ArrayList` so if I edit the `EventList` it will modify the source `ArrayList` too?

Comment: I want to clarify, in the second line, should the var 'list' be 'eventList'?

Comment: Yes, it should be `eventList`. Edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, Glazed Lists will not handle propagating changes in your event lists back to your underlying ArrayLists. In fact, in your example your event list and array list are not linked in any way -- the event list just contains all the same items as the array list. See the javadoc for the GlazedLists.eventList static helper [here](http://publicobject.com/glazedlists/glazedlists-1.8.0/api/ca/odell/glazedlists/GlazedLists.html#eventList%28java.util.Collection%29)

What you probably want to do is install a listener on your event list and propagate any changes to your array list. Also make sure that you manipulate the event list in response to GUI deletion events. If you modify the filter list the events won't propagate backwards to the event list.